# How to give separate permissions to GraphQL queries in AWS Amplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I need to give separate permissions to separate GraphQL queries. For example, currently I have defined two queries @auth gives permission to Admin group to these two queries. How can I give access to any logged in user(Cognito Pools) to `invokeLambda` query and only Admin group to `invokeGetGroups` query ? I can't seem to figure out how it is done.

```
type Query {
  @auth(
      rules: [
        { allow: groups, groups: ["Admins"] }])
  invokeLambda: String @function(name: "pythonLambda-${env}") 
  invokeGetGroups: String @function(name: "getPatchGroups-${env}")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@auth` rule within each function as so:

```
type Query {
  invokeLambda: String
    @function(name: "pythonLambda-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{allow: private, provider: userPools}])
  invokeGetGroups: String
    @function(name: "getPatchGroups-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["Admins"]}])

}
```

I haven't tried it with different auth rules, but I did try with the same auth rules on each function when I was following [an AWS tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/build-a-graph-application-with-amazon-neptune-and-aws-amplify/).

Comment: No problem, thanks for the edit.